# Nesting JPanels with different Layouts

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, gridbaglayout

I am currently trying to make a small project for work for myself to aid with my daily chores. I am trying to create a small table in Swing and started to add components. However, I am facing some difficulties.

First, let me highlight what I need to achieve. Photo underneath:

[image: Sample of what I am trying to achieve]

As per the code sample underneath I have tried to create a main Container, I have set its size to 600 x 300 and then created 3 JPanels (left, right and UpperBothJPanel to contain the other two of them).

I have set the GridLayout to the UpperBothJPanel to have an equal sized Table and GridBagLayout to the two (left and right JPanels) so I can modify their width separately. 
Then I have added 3 JLabels in the left one and 3 JLabels in the right one. 
Then added the right and left JPanel to the UpperBothJPanel.

However, I am having some difficulties:

1. If I change the size of the mainContainer, from 600x300 it appears not to work anymore. I do not understand to whom do I change the size now if not to the main Container?
2. If I set the upperBothPanel size to 150x200 it does not work. It continues to take all the space of the mainContainer.
3. The left and right JLabels are offset and not perfectly aligned, although the code is the same for both left and right JLabels.

   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Container;
   import java.awt.Dimension;
   import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
   import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
   import java.awt.GridLayout;
   import java.awt.Toolkit;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;

   public class Main extends JFrame {

   ```
   public String frameTitle, projectNameString, countryNameString, projectDetailString, requestDateString;
   private int offerRevisionVal;

   public JFrame frame;
   public Container mainContainer;
   private Toolkit toolkit;
   private JPanel upperBothPanels, upperLeftPanel, upperRightPanel, middlePanel, lowerPanel; // Main Panels where I added my smaller Objects
   private GridBagLayout upperLeftGridLayout, upperRightGridLayout;
   private GridLayout upperBothGridLayout;


   // UPPER OBJECTS
   private JLabel projectLabel, countryLabel, projectDetailLabel, offerLabel, requestDateLabel, emptyLabel;


   public Main(){

       frameTitle = "CRANES QUOTATIONS";

       // MAIN INSTANCE VARIABLES DEFINITION
       projectNameString = "Project Title"; // TO ADD LATER 
       countryNameString = "Brazil"; // TO ADD LATER
       projectDetailString = "32 Cranes biTravi"; // TO ADD LATER
       offerRevisionVal = 01; // TO ADD LATER
       requestDateString = "20-April-2017"; // tTO ADD LATER


       setTitle(frameTitle); // Added the main title of my App
       mainContainer = getContentPane(); // set up a Container to contain all my objects
       mainContainer.setBackground(Color.GREEN); // set the color of my ContentPane

       // UPER PANEL DEFINITION
       upperLeftPanel = new JPanel();
       //upperLeftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.red, 5, 5));


       // Definition place of my upper Grid Bag Layouts. One to hold them all.
       upperBothGridLayout = new GridLayout(2,1);

           upperLeftGridLayout = new GridBagLayout();




       upperLeftPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
       upperLeftPanel.setLayout(upperLeftGridLayout);


       // PLACE LEFT GRID
       GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();    

           projectLabel = new JLabel(projectNameString);
           c.weighty = 0.5;
           c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           c.gridx=0;
           c.gridy=0;
           upperLeftPanel.add(projectLabel, c);

           countryLabel = new JLabel(countryNameString);
           c.weighty=0.5;
           c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           c.gridx=0;
           c.gridy=1;
           upperLeftPanel.add(countryLabel, c);

           projectDetailLabel = new JLabel(projectDetailString);
           c.weighty = 0.5;
           c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           c.gridx = 0;
           c.gridy = 2;
           upperLeftPanel.add(projectDetailLabel, c);

           // PLACE RIGHT GRID
           upperRightPanel = new JPanel();
           upperRightPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
           upperRightGridLayout = new GridBagLayout();
           upperRightPanel.setLayout(upperRightGridLayout);
           //upperRightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.BLUE, 5, 5));

           GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();    

           offerLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(offerRevisionVal));
           d.weighty = 0.5;
           d.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           d.gridx=0;
           d.gridy=0;
           upperRightPanel.add(offerLabel, d);

           requestDateLabel = new JLabel(requestDateString);
           d.weighty=0.5;
           d.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           d.gridx=0;
           d.gridy=1;
           upperRightPanel.add(requestDateLabel, d);

           emptyLabel = new JLabel();
           d.weighty = 0.5;
           d.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
           d.gridx = 0;
           d.gridy = 2;
           upperRightPanel.add(emptyLabel, d);



           upperBothPanels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
           upperBothPanels.setSize(150,200);
           upperBothPanels.add(upperLeftPanel);
           upperBothPanels.add(upperRightPanel);


       // ===========================================================================  ADD THE PANELS


       mainContainer.add(upperBothPanels);

       // =========================================================================== 
       setSize(600, 300); // set the height and width of my window
       centerToScreen ();
       setVisible(true); // set visibility 
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // sets up what it does when I close the App.

   }

   // Method to center to screen
   public void centerToScreen (){
       toolkit = getToolkit();
       Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize(); // gets the screen size
       setLocation(size.width / 2 - getWidth() / 2, size.height / 2 - getHeight() / 2); // sets the location
   }
   ```

   }

/////////////////////

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CranesApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();

            }

        });


    }

}
```

Thank you in advance,
Best regards

Comment: What about instead creating and using a JTable?

Comment: If I add a JTable to contain my 3 rows 2 columns as per above then can I add underneath a new JTable with 10 rows and 4 columns and set to all the maximum size as per the previous JTable?